# Why is token replacement done before macro expansion?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Considering the following snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_MACRO(\
   arg) \
   arg

#define MY_MACRO2(t1, t2) t1##t2

#define MY_ a

#define MACRO b

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", MY_MACRO2(MY_,MACRO)(45));
    return 0;
}
```

It turns out to compile and display 45, however, if `MY_` and `MACRO` were expanded before substitution, this code should not compile.
The reason why I notice this is when I read in the C standard the following:

6.10.3.1 (but also in C++ standard)

*After  the  arguments  for  the  invocation  of  a  function-like macro  have  been  identified,argument  substitution  takes  place.A parameter  in  the  replacement  list,  unless  preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below), is replaced  by  the  corresponding  argument  **after  all  macros  contained  therein  have  been expanded**.    Before being   substituted,   each   argument’s preprocessing   tokens   are completely  macro  replaced  as  if  they formed  the  rest  of  the  preprocessing  file;  no  other preprocessing tokens are available*

So if all macros contained in the arguments were expanded before replacement, why don't we end up with `ab(45)`?

Comment: "unless preceded by a # or ## preprocessing token or followed by a ## preprocessing token (see below),"

Comment: Does the order of definitions change the behaviour?

Comment: @U.W. Why would it? Those macros are entirely unrelated, and the preprocessor doesn't have a mechanism for favoring macros which were defined "earlier"

Comment: See below (6.10.3.3): "If [...] a parameter is immediately preceded or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding argument’s preprocessing token sequence".

Comment: As a consequence of this, you can do [x-macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Answer (score 4):

To let constructions like `X(X())` work. Note that while `X()` is expanded the `X` macro is *disabled* to avoid infinite recursions. Expanding arguments before expanding the macro let's one use X in the arguments.
A practical application of `X(X())`:

```
#define TEN(x) x x x x x x x x x x
#define HUNDRED(x) TEN(TEN(x))
```